# SONARQUBE editor tab in eclipse shows nothing

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube

I have an java ejb project in my local drive.In the base directory i created sonar-project.properties file. After i started sonarqube in localhost:9000, I opened a command prompt and go to base directory and execute command sonar-runner. Project was successfully analyzed in localhost:9000.

Then I open eclipse and use the same project location as my workspace. When I associate this project with server running on localhost:9000 and do analyze, eclipse issue tab shows nothing. Also it does not show any errors.

What i am doing wrong?

sonar experts help me.

I am using,

1. Sonarqube 4.5
2. sonarqube java analyzer 3.3 plugin
3. Juno eclipse

Comment: Could you please provide the log of the SonarQube analysis run in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression that will be fixed in the upcoming 4.5.1 version of SonarQube. See [SONAR-5762](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5762).